# cannot contain user defined class in hash_set

Tags: c++, stl, msdn

I am implementing six degree Kevin Bacon problem and writing a class for the actor node.
I can use set but not hash_set container to hold a user defined class. why? the error msg shows:error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const ActorGraphNode' to 'size_t'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called....

```
#include <hash_set>
#include <set>
class ActorGraphNode{
    public: 
    string ActorName;
    //hash_set<ActorGraphNode> linkedActors;
    set<ActorGraphNode> linkedActors;
    ActorGraphNode(string name):ActorName(name){}
    void linkCostar(ActorGraphNode actor){
       linkedActors.insert(actor);
       actor.linkedActors.insert(*this);
    }
    bool operator<( const ActorGraphNode& a ) const
    { return ActorName < a.ActorName ? true : false;}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, `hash_set` requires you to implement a hash function for your type.

```
class ActorGraphNode{
    public: 
    string ActorName;
    hash_set<ActorGraphNode> linkedActors;
    //set<ActorGraphNode> linkedActors;
    ActorGraphNode(string name):ActorName(name){}
    void linkCostar(ActorGraphNode actor){
       linkedActors.insert(actor);
       actor.linkedActors.insert(*this);
    }
    bool operator<( const ActorGraphNode& a ) const
    { return ActorName < a.ActorName;}
    bool operator ==( const ActorGraphNode& a ) const
    { return ActorName == a.ActorName;}
    operator size_t() const
    {
      return hash<string>()(ActorName);
    }
};
```

Comment: You also need equality, and `operator<` is unnecessary for an unordered/hash containers.

Comment: Equality can be compiler generated, but sure, you can write your own if, say, you don't want to have the overhead of comparing the entire linkedActors set.

Comment: I think its better to make your own specialization for std::hash<ActorGraphNode> instead of making operator size_t

Comment: Evgeny, can u give me an example for how to write hash<ActorGraphNode>?  my original code cannot be compiled because operator size_t is missed that is why I added it.

Comment: @riv, `operator==` is not compiler generated. See §12, paragraph 1: "The default constructor (12.1), copy constructor and copy assignment operator (12.8), move constructor
and move assignment operator (12.8), and destructor (12.4) are special member functions. [ Note: The
implementation will implicitly declare these member functions for some class types when the program does
not explicitly declare them. The implementation will implicitly define them if they are odr-used (3.2).
See 12.1, 12.4 and 12.8. —end note ] Programs shall not define implicitly-declared special member functions."

Comment: @riv, ran out of room, these are the only compiler generated methods allowed.  If your compiler generates an `operator==`, it is an extension, and not standard.

Comment: @Nathan: oops you're right, I thought it was because there was no error, but apparently it ends up testing equality by casting the object to `size_t`.

Comment: @Evgeny Eltishev: `std::hash` is used by `unordered_set`; `hash_set` seems to use `stdext::hash_value`, at least in VC10. Switching to `unordered_set` will indeed make it easier, that way you will be able to drop the comparison operator, too.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for ur answers and comments. Here is my updated code with your help. plus for function linkCostar() I use pass by reference now:

```
class ActorGraphNode{
public: 
    string ActorName;
    hash_set<ActorGraphNode> linkedActors;
    ActorGraphNode(string name):ActorName(name){}
    void linkCostar(ActorGraphNode& actor){
        linkedActors.insert(actor);
        actor.linkedActors.insert(*this);
    }
    bool operator==( const ActorGraphNode& a ) const
    { return ActorName == a.ActorName ? true : false;}
    operator size_t() const
    {
        const int HASHSIZE = 501;
        int seed = 131;
        size_t sum = 0;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < ActorName.length(); ++i) 
            sum = (sum * seed) + ActorName[i];      
        return sum % HASHSIZE;
    }
};
```

Comment: STL has a hash function for strings so you don't have to write your own; if you do, don't return the result modulo `HASHSIZE`, you're basically increasing the number of collisions by forcing your values to 0..500 range.

Comment: thx riv, here is my update for operator size_t:  operator size_t() const
    {
       hash<string> H;
       return H(ActorName);
    }